# Curl returning corrupted data on RHEL5/6/7

Tags: curl, libcurl

I tried this on RHEL5, 6, and 7 boxes - and in all cases the returned data is corrupted.

While running:

```
curl https://my-server/my/web/service/service_name?xsd=../common/common_simple.xsd
```

the returned data is not the same as what I get via a web browser on Windows.

Also, wget works just fine from cmd line.

The diff between expected result and what I get with curl is as following:

```
431,432c431,432
<       <!--   [\-\s0-9a-zA-Z]{1,30}   -->
<       <xs:simpleType name="Test123ModelType">
---
>       <!--   [\-\s0-9a-boolean">
>               </xs:r  <xs:simpleType name="Test123ModelType">
```

The 2 lines above are the only difference between the files. The rest of content is identical.

File size that is retrived is the same in all cases (on all servers, both expected and corrupted contents).

Another interesting twist is that it happens in MOST times, but not every time. Once every 10 or so executions it returns correct content.

File size is 26566 bytes.

**Update**:
I ran curl with --trace option and I see the following in the trace output:

```
<= Recv data, 8208 bytes (0x2010)
1000: 2d 5c 73 30 2d 39 61 2d 62 6f 6f 6c 65 61 6e 22 -\s0-9a-boolean"
1010: 3e 0a 09 09 3c 2f 78 73 3a 72 09 3c 78 73 3a 73 >...</xs:r.<xs:s
1020: 69 6d 70 6c 65 54 79 70 65 20 6e 61 6d 65 3d 22 impleType name="
```

Which looks like the corrupt data is coming from the server. But, what I don't understand, is why it's working fine through a browser and wget.

**Update:** Tried specifying several different agent strings while running on Linux - no change in behavior was observed.

**Update:** Tried running the same on Windows 7, using both winssl and openssl versions of curl, and was unable to reproduce the problem. Also tried running via lynx text browser on Linux - didn't reproduce the problem that way either.

Any ideas for resolution / troubleshooting are very much appreciated.

Comment: As a first test, try altering the user-agent string your curl sends (with -A) and see how that changes anything (if at all).

Comment: I tried several different user-agent strings from useragentstrings.com, and result is the same.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: No, ended up not using curl.